# How to insert binary data into MSSQL using PDO

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

I am currently experiencing a weird error.

The setup:
MSSQL Server 2012 Express with a localdb 
The target table collation is: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

PHP 5.3.9 on a Zend Server 5.6
MCrypt with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 and MCRYPT_MODE_ECB

Sublime Text 2 default encoding (I read it is UTF8 BOM)

I am using PDO with the official MS adapter for the MSSQL server. Everything works fine apart from one thing:
I cannot write a row into my administrator table because of the password.

Lets have a look at my ENCRYPTED password:

```
y"ûƒ^äjw¾bðúl5êù-Ö=W¿Š±¬GP¥Œy÷&ø
```

This is the PDO Trace:

```
Array
(
    [0] => IMSSP
    [1] => -7
    [2] => An error occurred translating string for input param 3 to UCS-2: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page.


)
SQL: [120] INSERT INTO administrator ( [username], [email], [password], [section] )  VALUES(:username, :email, :password, :section)
Params:  4
Key: Name: [9] :username
paramno=0
name=[9] ":username"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [6] :email
paramno=1
name=[6] ":email"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [9] :password
paramno=2
name=[9] ":password"
is_param=1
param_type=2
Key: Name: [8] :section
paramno=3
name=[8] ":section"
is_param=1
param_type=2
```

When I use my MSSQL Management Center I can insert my row with the exact same SQL query. 
The column setup is fine I suppose:

```
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "int"
    ["username"]=>
    string(12) "nvarchar(45)"
    ["email"]=>
    string(12) "nvarchar(45)"
    ["password"]=>
    string(12) "varbinary(45)"
    ["section"]=>
    string(11) "nvarchar(7)"
    ["country_code"]=>
    string(11) "nvarchar(2)"
```

I use prepared statements and the `bindParam` function with not extra options to execute my SQL statements.

If anybody has an idea, how to solve that please let me know. Anykind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure about ms sql, but there must be a way to declare a binary column, ie no encoding or collation.

Comment: @Jack, Thanks for the comment. After that I tried the binary and varbinary columns, but those do not work either.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to perhaps bind the parameter as binary in PDO?

Comment: @Jack - I tried the `PDO::PARAM_LOB` which is apparently supposed to deal with binary stuff - did not work as well.

Comment: In that case I'm out of ideas besides using base64 encoding :) 25% overhead

Comment: Just out of interest, I hope you have a good reason to *encrypt* a password as opposed to *hashing* it. Also, you may want to rephrase your question to ask *"How to insert binary data into MSSQL using PDO"*, it may attract more/the right attention.

Comment: @deceze - It is hashed but on top of that encrypted with 16 rounds. The L**ked*n has probably shown enough reasons.

Comment: Have you tried **bindParam(2,  $password, PDO::PARAM_LOB, 0, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_BINARY);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your collation to something like `utf8_unicode_ci` to handle those few unattended characters.

Also you should try something like this:

```
$db = new PDO('foo', 'bar', 'blo');
$stmt = $db->prepare("select foo, bar from table where id=?");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$stmt->bindColumn(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$stmt->bindColumn(2, $lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
header("Content-Type: $type");
fpassthru($lob);
```

To double check the type (this is where the error/bug starts happening) do this check, perhaps even in place of the last line of my example above:

```
if (is_string($lob)) echo $lob;
else fpassthru($lob);
```